# Woocommerce how to find original hook functions? e.g woocommerce_shop_loop

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I want to alter the way the prodcuts are represented on the shop page but I am not able to find the original hook functions so I can alter them accordingly. Where can I find the original functions of the hooks from product-archive.php? For example woocommerce_shop_loop or how to generally find this functions?

I already read through all the files. From product-archive.php I was lead to:
    plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php

and some of the functions I finally found in: 
    plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php

But woocommerce_shop_loop or woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title
are still missing.

I expect there to be some system, or indications in the product-archive.php file leading to the original function.

Answer (score 0):

They list all the hooks and the files that hold them here:[Hook Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)
Also you can Grep for the hook's name in the WooCommerce folder.

Comment: Does not help a lot: When I look for _woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_ I find the reference to where the action is added. But the function for this action e.g. _add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );_ where can I find that one?

Comment: You can search for the callback as well as the action. The callback for that action is in the includes folder. It is called wc-template-functions.php.